# In a finite non-abelian group $(G,+)$, is $a+b=c+d$ if and only if $b+a=d+c$ for all non-identity $a,b,c,d\in G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Pretty much just the title.  In a finite non-abelian group $(G,+)$, is it true that for any $a,b,c,d\in G\setminus\{e\}$, $a+b=c+d$ if and only if $b+a=d+c$?  I have tried using proof by contradiction (i.e. assuming $a+b\not= c+d$ but $b+a=d+c$), but was unable to make any progress.

I have been asked to provide more context, so here goes.  My professor assigned the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a finite multiplicative group with identity 1 and let $D\subseteq G$. Prove that the following are equivalent: (1) For any $g\in G\setminus\{1\}$, there are exactly $\lambda$ distinct $(x,y)\in D\times D$ s.t. $g=xy^{-1}$.  (2) For any $g\in G\setminus\{1\}$, there are exactly $\lambda$ distinct $(x,y)\in D\times D$ s.t. $g=x^{-1}y$.

There's no assigned book for the class, so I have no idea where he got the problem.  We'd been studying difference sets, but until this problem, we'd only considered them in abelian groups.  My thought was that if I can prove the statement I made in the title, I can prove that the statement is true for difference sets with $\lambda=1$, then use that to prove the statement for general $\lambda$.

Answer (score 8):

No.  For instance, taking $d$ to be the identity element and $c=a+b$, this would say that $a+b=c=b+a$ for all $a,b\in G$, so that $G$ is abelian.